# Find all git commits matching a certain 'count of commits'

Tags: linux, git, bash

I use the following command to generate an ID (count of commits) similar to the svn (Subversion) 'Revision number'.

```
git rev-list HEAD | wc -l
# With newer git versions you can also use:
git rev-list HEAD --count
```

I'm aware that this is not exactly the same as in svn and particularly that my Git-IDs are not necessarily unique. Still it is good enough for my purposes (distinguishing at a quick glance which of two builds is more recent).

**Now my question:**

Supposing I have the ID 2340 how can I find all Git revisions (hashes) that match this ID (count of commits)?

**EDIT (example)**

```
*   9c4365c count: 5
|\
| |
| |   
| * b1a9954 count: 2
| |
| |
| |   
* | 7e8831a count: 3
| |
| |
| |   
* | e8cabc4 count: 2
|/
|
|  
* 9ae0137 count: 1
```

For ID (count) 2 I would like to get e8cabc4 and b1a9954.

A very inefficient solution would be to iterate over all commits and check the 'count' for that commit. If it matches, add it to the solution.

Comment: Commits are sets of changes. Count of commits is a number. The two don't compare. Please explain exactly what you want to do, preferably with an example.

Comment: The question is unclear. Where does the tree-output come from, and how does it relate to the count? Given the tree-output, could you not just `grep` or `awk` out the relevant revisions?

Comment: The tree output is just to give an idea how a repository might look. Generating that tree automatically would involve iterating over all commits and calculating the 'count' for each one, which is inefficient. Another way of putting the question: The count is the number of commits between the first commit of the repository and the current commit. Given the count N, which commits are N commits away from the first commit of the repository?

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth this is the inefficient solution I mentioned in the question.

```
#!/bin/bash

MY_COUNT=2340

for COMMIT in `git rev-list HEAD`
do
    CCOUNT=`git rev-list ${COMMIT} --count`
    if [ "${CCOUNT}" == "${MY_COUNT}" ]
    then
        echo $COMMIT
    fi
done
```

For a repository with 3000 commits it takes about 30 seconds.

Comment: Do this once and store it somewhere, next commit rebuild for new commits only. Then you can simply `grep` for the number.